# Group array by nested keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

does anyone know of a ES6 or Ramda way to group an array of objects by an object key then create a new array of objects based on the grouping? For example, I have an array of objects as follow:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ABCD123",
    "code": "GFDGF",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ABCD123ABCD",
    "code": "LOLL23",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN 2",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to have a new array that's grouped by `ptj.desc` or `ptj.code`:

```
[
  {
    "PTJ": "ABCD 123",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "ABCD123",
        "code": "GFDGF",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "123",
          "desc": "ABCD 123"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "POTER UTAMA",
        "code": "POTER345",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "123",
          "desc": "ABCD 123"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "ABCD123ABCD",
        "code": "LOLL23",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "123",
          "desc": "ABCD 123"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "POTER UTAMA",
        "code": "POTER345",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "123",
          "desc": "ABCD 123"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "PTJ": "111 123",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "ANGGUN",
        "code": "DSFD54",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "111",
          "desc": "111 123"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "GDFDGG",
        "code": "HJ2",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "111",
          "desc": "111 123"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "ANGGUN 2",
        "code": "DSFD54",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "111",
          "desc": "111 123"
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "PTJ": "222 123",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "POT",
        "code": "POT89",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "222",
          "desc": "222 123"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "POT",
        "code": "POT89",
        "ptj": {
          "code": "222",
          "desc": "222 123"
        }
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

So far what I have is this

```
const stores = myArray.reduce((r, a) => {
    r[a.ptj.desc] = r[a.ptj.desc] || [];
    r[a.ptj.desc].push(a);
    return r;
}, {});
```

Unfortunately it convert to object and I can't use `array.map`. What did I do wrong? I welcome to correct and improve it using ES6 or ramda. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to group the objects with the same `ptj.desc` value and don't mind the resulting value being an object with the index for keys, then you can just use `R.groupBy` like so:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "ABCD123",
    "code": "GFDGF",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ABCD123ABCD",
    "code": "LOLL23",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN 2",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  }
]

const fn = R.groupBy(R.path(['ptj','desc']))

console.log(fn(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

If you do want to end up with the same structure as the example in your question, then you can compose the above with `R.map`, `R.zipObj` and `R.toPairs` like so:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "ABCD123",
    "code": "GFDGF",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ABCD123ABCD",
    "code": "LOLL23",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN 2",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  }
]

const fn = R.groupBy(R.path(['ptj','desc']))

const fn2 = R.compose(R.map(R.zipObj(['PTJ', 'data'])), R.toPairs, fn)

console.log(fn2(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group by `ptj.desc` or `ptj.code`. The example below uses `ptj.desc`.

```js
let proj = [{"name":"ABCD123","code":"GFDGF","ptj":{"code":"123","desc":"ABCD 123"}},{"name":"ANGGUN","code":"DSFD54","ptj":{"code":"111","desc":"111 123"}},{"name":"GDFDGG","code":"HJ2","ptj":{"code":"111","desc":"111 123"}},{"name":"POT","code":"POT89","ptj":{"code":"222","desc":"222 123"}},{"name":"POTER UTAMA","code":"POTER345","ptj":{"code":"123","desc":"ABCD 123"}},{"name":"ABCD123ABCD","code":"LOLL23","ptj":{"code":"123","desc":"ABCD 123"}},{"name":"ANGGUN 2","code":"DSFD54","ptj":{"code":"111","desc":"111 123"}},{"name":"GDFDGG","code":"HJ2","ptj":{"code":"111","desc":"111 123"}},{"name":"POT","code":"POT89","ptj":{"code":"222","desc":"222 123"}},{"name":"POTER UTAMA","code":"POTER345","ptj":{"code":"123","desc":"ABCD 123"}}]

result = proj.reduce(function (a, c) {
  a[c.ptj.desc] = a[c.ptj.desc] || [];
  a[c.ptj.desc].push(c)
  return a;
}, Object.create(null));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of doing this but what you describe here falls in line with id => val lookup.

You first create an array of all the keys (so `{}.ptj.desc`), then map all the objects onto a new object (map) whose keys match the above array's, then...profit.

See example below.  Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

```js
var mainStore = [
  {
    "name": "ABCD123",
    "code": "GFDGF",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ABCD123ABCD",
    "code": "LOLL23",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "ANGGUN 2",
    "code": "DSFD54",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "GDFDGG",
    "code": "HJ2",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "111",
      "desc": "111 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POT",
    "code": "POT89",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "222",
      "desc": "222 123"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "POTER UTAMA",
    "code": "POTER345",
    "ptj": {
      "code": "123",
      "desc": "ABCD 123"
    }
  }
];

var idList = mainStore.map(item => item.ptj.desc);

var dataMap = mainStore.reduce(( dataMap, item ) => {
  dataMap[ item.ptj.desc ] = item;
  return dataMap;
}, {});

// Then do everything based on idList 

var onlyCodes = idList.map(id => dataMap[ id ].ptj.code);
var onlyNames = idList.map(id => dataMap[ id ].name);

console.log(onlyCodes);
console.log(onlyNames);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use map, you could try something like this:

```
let yourArray = Object.keys(stores).map(key => stores[key])
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `Object.values(stores)`?